# ng-select gives only string, but I want an integer

Tags: angularjs, select

This is my angular html file code. In my mongo database `frequencyType` added as `frequencyType = "1"`, but I want `frequencyType = NumberInt(1);`

```html
<div class="span4">
  <select class="span12 combobox" ng-model="frequencyType" required>
    <option value="1">Daily</option>
    <option value="2">Weekly</option>
    <option value="3">Monthly</option>
    <option value="4">Yearly</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I get in my database `frequencyType = "1"` but I want `frequencyType = NumberInt(1)`.

Comment: Please reconsider your selected answer as it is only partially correct. As Trak mentioned in his answer the _accepted_ answer doesn't work for situations where his answer **does** work. When another person like me comes along I'd rather see the "most correct" answer selected. Luckily, I don't take anything at face value or else I'd have found out the hard way the "answer" would not have worked for me. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suggest you to try to use `indexOf`.

**JS**

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.values = ["Daily","Weekly","Monthly","Yearly"];
    $scope.selectedItem = 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="values.indexOf(selectedItem) as selectedItem for selectedItem in values"></select>
    selectedItem: {{selectedItem}}
</div>
```

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EyBVN/38/)**</kbd>

So send to mongoDB `$scope.selectedItem` value

Comment: That did help me very much. It seems simple yet took my more than half an hour already :(

Comment: This doesn't work when your values are specific codes or id's. The solution by Trak below works for all numeric values.

Comment: @Erwin do you want to give an example with my demo? If i'll put `[1,2,3,4,5];` it still works

Comment: @MaximShoustin I have a list of objects with a value and discription field, with ng-options="code.value as code.discription for code in object.codes" and ng-model="codeField". codeField needs to store the value of the code, which are not equal to the indexes. When I use 'object.codes.indexOf(code)', it stores the index on the field which should get filled with the code.

Comment: What if the IDs are [32,12,44,1,900]? This works if selecting by index only. I think this is a good solution for enums that always start from 0

Answer (score 61):

There is an easier way:

Just use `value*1` as your id, that will convert the string to int without changing the value... assuming the id is an integer.

so the result is>

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="selectedItem*1 as selectedItem for selectedItem in values"></select>
    selectedItem: {{selectedItem}}
</div>
```

This will work in more cases, since indexOf is not available in objects, only in arrays. This solution works for objects with integers as keys (for example if some keys are missing, or if you use db ids)

Comment: But what if it's not an integer? Generally, assumptions are bad ;-)

Comment: The question asks about keys as integers, if it's not an integer, and it is a string, then more assumptions are being made, since you're trusting the order of the datasource

Comment: Better than adding a conversion directive to parse (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28114970/angularjs-ng-options-using-number-for-model-does-not-select-initial-value)

Comment: I think "+selectedItem" is alittle bit nicer, but it works the same

Answer (score 48):

Most solutions discussed here require using the ngOptions directive instead of using static `<option>` elements in the HTML code, as was the case in the OP's code.

## Angular 1.6.x

**Edit** If you use Angular 1.6.x, just use the [ng-value](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue) directive and it will work as expected.

```js
angular.module('nonStringSelect', [])
.run(function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.model = { id: 2 };
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="nonStringSelect">
  <select ng-model="model.id">
    <option ng-value="0">Zero</option>
    <option ng-value="1">One</option>
    <option ng-value="2">Two</option>
  </select>
  
  {{ model }}
</div>
```

## Older versions

There *is* a way to make it work while still using static elements. It's shown in the AngularJS select directive documentation.

The idea is to use a directive to register a parser and a formatter on the model. The parser will do the string-to-int conversion when the item is selected, while the formatter will do the int-to-string conversion when the model changes.

Code below (taken directly from the AngularJS documentation page, credit not mine).

https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.6/docs/api/ng/directive/select#binding-select-to-a-non-string-value-via-ngmodel-parsing-formatting

```js
angular.module('nonStringSelect', [])
.run(function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.model = { id: 2 };
})
.directive('convertToNumber', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      ngModel.$parsers.push(function(val) {
        return parseInt(val, 10);
      });
      ngModel.$formatters.push(function(val) {
        return '' + val;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="nonStringSelect">
  <select ng-model="model.id" convert-to-number>
    <option value="0">Zero</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
  </select>
  
  {{ model }}
</div>
```

Comment: Great solution! This should be the accepted answer. +1

Comment: Been searching for long, and this one's perfect!

Comment: This is definitely a much more practical solution for AngularJS 1.6+ as ng-options can be problematic due to strict comparison.

Answer (score 33):

I've just had the same problem and figured out the right way to do this - no 'magic' required. :)

```js
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.values = [
        {name : "Daily", id : 1},
        {name : "Weekly", id : 2},
        {name : "Monthly", id : 3},
        {name : "Yearly", id : 4}];
    $scope.selectedItem = $scope.values[0].id;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="selectedItem.id as selectedItem.name for selectedItem in values"></select>
    selectedItem: {{selectedItem}}
</div>
```

Comment: This is the right answer, forget the other solutions

Comment: This is worked for me, and seems logically the right answer. Configuration is easy to follow, and Angular docs back up ng-options syntax.

Answer (score 12):

I think the angular way to do this is to use the directive "convert-to-number" in the select tag.

```
<select class="span12 combobox" ng-model="frequencyType" required convert-to-number>
    <option value="1">Daily</option>
    <option value="2">Weekly</option>
    <option value="3">Monthly</option>
    <option value="4">Yearly</option>
</select>
```

You can see the documentation and a fiddle here at the end of the page : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Answer (score 8):

This is the easiest way I have found so far:

```js
function Controller($scope) {
    $scope.options = {
        "First option" : 1,
        "Second option" : 2,
        "Last option" : 10
    }
    $scope.myoption = 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="Controller">    
    <select ng-model="myoption" ng-options="label for (label, value) in options"></select>
    Option Selected: {{myoption}}
</div>
```

Or, if you want to use numeric indexes:

```js
function Controller($scope) {
    $scope.options = {
        1 : "First option",
        2 : "Second option",
        10 : "Last option"
    }
    $scope.myoption = 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="Controller">    
    <select ng-model="myoption" ng-options="value*1 as label for (value, label) in options"></select>
    Option Selected: {{myoption}}
</div>
```

For Angular 2, [follow the rabit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33181936/how-to-use-select-option-ngfor-on-an-array-of-objects-in-angular2)...