# ngmodel not binding integer values on select tag

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I will be getting the selected value as integer from service and need to send it back as integer. please check the [Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/R7QfJfy6m6IgHKL07tFI?p=preview) for code

```
<!-- Working -->
<div ng-init="selectedvalue = '3'">
    <select ng-model="selectedvalue">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>
</div>
<!-- Not Working -->
<div ng-init="selectedvalue2 = 3">
    <select ng-model="selectedvalue2">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>
</div>
<!-- Not Working -->
<div ng-init="selectedvalue3 = 3">
    <select ng-model="selectedvalue3">
    <option value=1>1</option>
    <option value=2>2</option>
    <option value=3>3</option>
    <option value=4>4</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/R7QfJfy6m6IgHKL07tFI?p=preview

Comment: I know that this is annoying but you always can parse t as int using `parseInt`.

Comment: [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28114970/angularjs-ng-options-using-number-for-model-does-not-select-initial-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a directive to parse string to int. e.g. `convert-to-number` on your select tag:

```
<select ng-model="selectedvalue" convert-to-number>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Then you can have

```
.directive('convertToNumber', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      ngModel.$parsers.push(function(val) {
        return parseInt(val, 10);
      });
      ngModel.$formatters.push(function(val) {
        return '' + val;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 3):

in ng-model you can add a filter number to convert like this:

```
ng-model="selectedvalue3 | number"
```

Comment: specify version

Answer (score 1):

you can follow this process `select as label for value in array` and better way to initialize value from controller.

Like in controller :

```
$scope.selectedvalue3 = 30;
$scope.infos= [{age:21, name:"xx"},{age:20, name:"yyy"},{age:30, name:"zzz"},{age:40, name:"ppp"}];
```

and in HTML:

```
<div>
     <select ng-options="info.age as info.age for info in infos" ng-model="selectedvalue3"></select>
</div>
```

where age is integer value . it may help you

Answer (score 0):

The value in select are interpreted like string.

You must work with string and convert/parse your value after or before.