# AngularJS select with hard coded options

Tags: angularjs

**Q.** Why my drop down is not showing the selcted value ? 
Here is the javascript code that i have

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
 <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
     <select ng-model="myModel.Active" convert-to-number>
       <option value="-1">Select</option>
       <option value="1">Yes</option>
       <option value="2">No</option>
       <option value="3">Maybe</option>
     </select>
     <span>{{myModel.Active}}</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

The javascript

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp",[]);
myApp.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope){
      $scope.myModel = {};
      $scope.myModel.Active=2; // 

});
```

**The js-fiddle link** -- https://jsfiddle.net/shatherali/4mxwzL5y/19/

**Edit:** Please note i dont want to use string value. Active has to be a number value.

Comment: The `convert-to-number` from http://stackoverflow.com/a/34114258/652669 doesn't work?

Comment: Not for me atleast, may be i am doing wrong something that i cannot figure out. I updated fiddle with convert-to-number

Comment: See my answer, I linked a demo with `convert-to-number` which works fine. Hope it would help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solves your issue:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
      $scope.myModel = {};
      $scope.myModel.Active = '2'; // it's a string
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/4mxwzL5y/18/)**</kbd>

---

The `convert-to-number` directive works fine.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('convertToNumber', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$parsers.push(function(val) {
                return parseInt(val, 10);
            });
            ngModel.$formatters.push(function(val) {
                return '' + val;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/4mxwzL5y/21/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, i just update my question, i cannot change the value to string, it has to stay number

Comment: So basically the solution is either use the string value or create your own directive to take use that value ( just like you did ), any idea why built in convert-to-number directive not working ?

Comment: That's not a built-in directive! :) Actually they make their `select` directive to be used with the `ng-options` attribute. They should have done an `option` directive to override the default one but they didn't, so you have to use string values or to "hack" it. :/

Comment: Ahhh my bad, actually i did look at the code example at the botton of the angular select documentation page, but never paid attention to the plunker code and thought that its a built in directive. Thanks again.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select