# Angularjs ng-options using number for model does not work (even with 'convertToNumber' directive)

Tags: angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I'm trying to use ng-options with a  to bind a numeric integer value to a list of corresponding options:

```
angular.module('nonStringSelect', [])
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.loadedModels = [
    {
      id_category: 1,
      title: 'Category A',
    },
    {
      id_category: 2,
      title: 'Category B',
    },
    {
      id_category: 3,
      title: 'Category C',
    },
  ];
  $scope.model = 3;
})
.directive('convertToNumber', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      ngModel.$parsers.push(function(val) {
        return parseInt(val, 10);
      });
      ngModel.$formatters.push(function(val) {
        return '' + val;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="nonStringSelect" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select ng-model="model" ng-options="item.title for item in loadedModels track by item.id_category" convert-to-number>
</select>
{{ model }}
</body>
```

At first, I tried using

```
<select ng-model="model" ng-options="item.id_category as item.title for item in loadedModels" convert-to-number>
```

but it produced

```
<option value="number:1" label="Category A">Category A</option>
```

Now I use

```
ng-options="item.title for item in loadedModels track by item.id_category"
```

and it generated the correct options:

```
<option value="1" label="Category A">Category A</option>
```

I tried to follow the answer described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28114970/angularjs-ng-options-using-number-for-model-does-not-select-initial-value) but it doesn't work. When the page is loaded no item is selected in the list and whenever I select any item the model becomes NaN.

Here is a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Co4UeHLiRgZ2MENSDjNc?p=preview).

Comment: `value="number:1"` precisely shows that the select is bound to a numeric value in the scope. http://plnkr.co/edit/qwdW0xfKOJX0aEntLmzz?p=preview

Comment: @JB Nizet, yes, but when I try to save the model to database it gives me validation error that the value is not valid integer, since string "number:1" cannot be converted to int.

Comment: Well, you're not supposed to submit the form directly. You're supposed to call a method ofyour controller that uses $http to post the bound data as JSON. That's how angular is designed to work.

Comment: But still I need the dropdown to show a pre-selected item when the page is loaded.