# ng-model having a string value and ng-option integer

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my JSON array:

```
array=[ {id:1, name:'A'} , {id:2, name:'B'} ]
```

And in ng-model I am setting value which may be string like

```
modelValue='1'
```

I had ng-option

```
ng-option="option.id as option.name for option in array"
ng-model="modelValue"
```

But it is not showing selected value of ng-model in select

Comment: typo : ng-optionS, you forgot the 's'.

Comment: @Walfrat That was typo while typing in stack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And in ng-model I am setting value which may be string like

You should provide the same `primitive or object type` to your `$scope.modelValue` as of `id`. This is the preferred way.

If only the `JSON array` is being fetched dynamically AND type consistency is not guaranteed then you can apply a function to convert it to the type that is set to `$scope.modelValue`

In HTML

```
<select ng-model="modelValue" ng-options="getId(option.id) as option.name for option in myarray"> 

</select>
```

In Controller

```
$scope.modelValue='1';

$scope.myarray=[ {id:1, name:'A'} , {id:2, name:'B'} ];

$scope.getId = function(id)
{
   if(typeof $scope.modelValue == "string")
     return String(id);
   else if(typeof $scope.modelValue == "number")
     return parseInt(id);
}
```

**[COMPLETE EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Kunalh/4hfL2wxz/7/)**

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34114258/4331291) answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working JSFiddle example based on your description: http://jsfiddle.net/9pLdgmm1/1/

You should use `ng-options` instead of `ng-option`

```
<select ng-options="p.name for p in people"
        ng-model="selectedPerson">
</select>
```

Comment: I have integer value in ng-option and string in model.

Comment: Thank you. But I got the perfect solution what I want by Nishant123

Answer (score 0):

You should take `ng-options` instead of `ng-option`, als you should take `integer` itself instead of string..

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<select ng-model="modelValue" ng-options="option.id as option.name for option in names">
</select>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [ {id:1, name:'A'} , {id:2, name:'B'} ]
    $scope.modelValue = 1;
});
</script>

<p>This example shows how to fill a dropdown list using the ng-options directive.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

**Please run the above snippet**

[**Here is a Working DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/zp4Lh9es/)

Answer (score 0):

This should not be selected, because of all id is in numbers. If you want to make it select, then parse your $scope.modelValue to numbers like this.

```
$scope.modelValue= parseInt("1");
```

Also change your ng-options instead of ng-option

Answer (score -1):

You have a syntax error in `ng-options`:

```
<select ng-options="option.name for option in array" ng-model="modelValue"></select>
```

---

```js
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.array = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'A'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'B'
  }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp">
  <fieldset ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
    <select ng-options="option.name for option in array" ng-model="modelValue"></select>
    modelValue is: {{modelValue}}
  </fieldset>
</div>
```