# Dropdown can't pull number value from object (Angular 4)

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I'm pulling data from an API, which is going fine unless I bind my JSON option number value into the [value] tag. see example:

**WORKING** (data got from API is selected on the option)

```
<select [(ngModel)]="data.from.api.one" class="form-control">
<option *ngFor="let c of subdimension" [value]="c.name">{{ c.name }}</option>
</select> <!-- select with c.name on value -->
```

**NOT WORKING** (data is not selected and the first option is null)

```
<select [(ngModel)]="data.from.api.one" class="form-control">
<option *ngFor="let c of subdimension" [value]="c.value">{{ c.name }}</option>
</select> <!-- select with c.value on value -->
```

**JSON object:**

```
subdimension = [{'name': 'sub1','value': 2  },
  {'name': 'sub2','value': 4 },
  {'name': 'sub3','value': 8}]
```

What I want to do is to bind a number value into some selects and then sum all of them like:

data.from.api.one + data.from.api.two...

**EDIT:**

Component code from the data.from.api

```
constructor (public dataService:DataService){
    this.dataService.getData().subscribe(datas => {
      this.datas = datas;
    });
  }

getData(){
return this.http.get('https://api.url/').map(res => res.json());
              }

datas:Data[];

data = {
  from:{api:{one:'',two:'',three:''}}
}
```

Comment: by any chance are you setting a defaut value to **data.form.api.one** if so please post a bit of the component where this gets set.

Comment: @Sonicd300 Edited with code

Comment: Very similar question but AngularJS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28114970/angularjs-ng-options-using-number-for-model-does-not-select-initial-value ... Issue is that "select" options have to be strings, but you're trying to use a number value directly. Perhaps fixed if you parse to/from strings?

Comment: @mc01 just realized this is not just for numbers, I added a new string properties on the json object and still the same problem. It only works if I put the c.name on [value] (which is equal from the string that is calling from the API). The question is, how to I bind it to another value differently from the c.name?

Answer (score 0):

Everything works. i have created [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/7XIQBIngExRQ3B29a3mF?p=preview). You need to setUp ngModel value after request.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="data.from.api.one" class="form-control">
 <option *ngFor="let c of subdimension; let i = index" [ngValue]="c">{{ 
   c.name }}</option>
 </select>
```

and if you want pure number

```
<select [(ngModel)]="data.from.api.one" class="form-control">
 <option *ngFor="let c of subdimension; let i = index" [value]="c.value">{{ 
   c.name }}</option>
 </select>
```

In your code use this code in ngOnInit hook

```
return this.http.get('https://api.url/').map(res => res.json()).do((d) => {

     this.subdimension = d;
        //if you use object
        this.data.from.api.one = d[0]
        //if you use value
        this.data.from.api.one1 = d[0].value
     })
```

or

```
 this.dataService.getData().subscribe(datas => {
  this.datas = datas;
   this.data.from.api.one = datas[0]
        //if you use value
        this.data.from.api.one1 = datas[0].value
});
```

Comment: Ok :-) Just being polite

Comment: @alexKhymenko This is not the problem. The problem is when the data is get from the API and I bind it with a number value, the data is simply not pulled (e.g. https://imgur.com/a/BMYr6). The first one is c.name and the second one is c.value on [value] tag. I'm not sure why this happens when I put it as c.value.

Comment: You mean default value?? Cause its setting c.value in model.

Comment: Added 2 example on object and on value. Good luck!!

Comment: Sorry I couldn't made it work. I have updated this post with my api-get component code. Maybe this could give you a better perspective of my issue.

Comment: Add one more map to request where you will set up ng model

Comment: Even better not map use do

Comment: @Gustavo Updated. Verify pls works. And im out for today :-) Updated plunker