# Binding ngModel to a model for a select control

Tags: angular

In Angular 1.x, you could bind ngModel to a model for a select control:

```
<select ng-model="selectedPerson" 
   ng-options="person as person.name for person in people">
</select>
```

When an option is selected, the `selectedPerson` model will point to the `person` model that the user selected.

Is there a way to do the same thing in Angular2?

I've tried the following with no luck:

```
<select [(ngModel)] = "selectedPerson"> 
     <option *ngFor="#person of people"> {{ person.name }}</option>
</select>
```

I've also tried:

```
<select [(ngModel)] = "selectedPerson"> 
     <option *ngFor="#person of people" [value]="person"> {{ person.name }}</option>
</select>
```

In the first attempt, `selectedPerson` model references `person.name` rather than the `person` object.  And in the second attempt, it is referencing an object, which doesn't appear to be a JSON object.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Is this even possible?

Comment: I don't think it is possible at present. See this https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4843

Answer (score 4):

You could implement a `<select>` inside a form using the `FormBuilder` directive:

```
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

export class LoginPage {

  constructor(form: FormBuilder) {
    this.cities = ["Shimla", "New Delhi", "New York"]; // List of cities
    this.loginForm = form.group({
      username: ["", Validators.required],
      password: ["", Validators.required],
      city: ["", Validators.required] // Setting the field to "required"
    });
  }

  login(ev) {
    console.log(this.loginForm.value); // {username: <username>, password: <password>, city: <city>}
  }

}
```

In your .html:

```
<form [ngFormModel]="loginForm" (submit)="login($event)">

    <input type="text" ngControl="username">
    <input type="password" ngControl="password">
    <select ngControl="city">
        <option *ngFor="#c of cities" [value]="c">{{c}}</option>
    </select>
    <button block type="submit" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid">Submit</button>

</form>
```

[Official Documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormBuilder-class.html)

Comment: This isn't what I'm after. Using ngControl still binds to the value of the input control, rather than the model. When a drop down is selected, I am trying to bind selectedPerson to the model { name:'' } rather than just name. Try updating your example to use models where a city is an object: { name: }. You will see that loginForm.city is just a string.

Comment: @pixelbits Why don't you simply set `this.selectedPerson = {}` inside your constructor, and then `[(ngModel)] = "selectedPerson.name"` with a `[value]=person.name` in the options? This will result in: `selectedPerson: {name: "<name>"}`.

Comment: That is not the same as binding to a model. I could be retrieving these objects from a DB. I'm looking for the equivalent of ng-options="person as person.name for person in people"

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue trying to pass an object as selected value to a ngModel. An alternative solution I see is to use a stringified version of the object passing to a string, but that is very dirty.

In the end I have decided to create a separate index in the object which gets passed to the ngModel. This I use to select the Object and do the action.

Also issue raised in : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4843
and [How to use select/option/NgFor on an array of objects in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33181936/how-to-use-select-option-ngfor-on-an-array-of-objects-in-angular2)