# Non-string values from form controls in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms

In Angular2, is there a clean way to handle a form control's value as something else than a string, for example have a `<select>` with options `(bool) true` and `(bool) false`?

Currently I'm using solutions that don't feel very elegant:

```
<select (change)="model.published = !!$event.target.value">
    <option value="">No</option>
    <option value="1">Yes</option>
</select>

<select (change)="model.type = $event.target.value * 1">
    <option value="1">My value is (int) 1</option>
    <option value="2">My value is (int) 2</option>
</select>
```

I'm using `<select>`s in my example, but I'm interested in other form controls as well.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33181936/how-to-use-select-option-ngfor-on-an-array-of-objects-in-angular2) was suggested as a duplicate, but I'm don't think it is one since I'm not

1. interested only in selects
2. trying to generate options dynamically

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use select/option/NgFor on an array of objects in Angular2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33181936/how-to-use-select-option-ngfor-on-an-array-of-objects-in-angular2)

Comment: Good question, I have exactly the same problem.. Your solution is the best I have found so far, but I agree that it isn't very elegant.. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known limitation in the current Angular version https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2551

Answer (score 1):

Yea just add `[(ngModel)]="model.published"` to the select and it'll set the `value` property of the `<option>` selected, if you add an object in the `<option>` like this: `<option value="{{object}}">` you'll set an object, it doesn't have to be a string.

Comment: But since I don't have the possible values in an object or array, how would this work?

Comment: `<option value="{{false}}">No</option>` `<option value="{{true}}">Yes</option>`, but for booleans I dont think you have to use {{}} they should convert if you bind the select to a boolean property by just using: `<option value="false">No</option>` `<option value="true">Yes</option>`

Comment: That does not seem to work. The values still end up as strings into the model.