# How to get number in [(ngModel)] in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

How to get number in [(ngModel)] in Angular 2?

```
<select [(ngModel)]="levelNum">
    <option *ngFor="#level of levels" [value]="level.num">{{level.name}}</option>
</select>

levelNum:number;
levels:Array<Object> = [
    {num: 0, name: "AA"},
    {num: 1, name: "BB"}
];
```

I tried to add `type="number"` in different places.

```
 <select type="number" [(ngModel)]="levelNum">
    <option *ngFor="#level of levels" [value]="level.num">{{level.name}}</option>
</select>
```

and

```
 <select [(ngModel)]="levelNum">
    <option type="number" *ngFor="#level of levels" [value]="level.num">{{level.name}}</option>
</select>
```

But when I select a new item, `levelNum` still becomes a string.

Comment: What happens if you define an interface and use it instead of object where num is a number type?

Comment: @DavidL I actually have an `interface Level {num:number, name:string}`, but still same

Comment: @HongboMiao here is the same [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33181936/2435473) with no helpful answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The **Select** with *ngFor in Angular2 seems to not work properly when using objects.  They have opened the issue in [github](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4843) but it still hasn't been resolved.

Until this is fixed I would do something like changing the string value to a number whenever the select value is changed.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template:`
    <h1>Selecting Number</h1>
    <select type="number" [(ngModel)]="levelNum" (ngModelChange)="toNumber()">
      <option *ngFor="#level of levels" [value]="level.num">{{level.name}}</option>
    </select>
    {{levelNum}}
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  levelNum:number;
  levels:Array<Object> = [
      {num: 0, name: "AA"},
      {num: 1, name: "BB"}
  ];

  toNumber(){
    this.levelNum = +this.levelNum;
    console.log(this.levelNum);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, a nice trick!

Comment: For arrays just use: this.list = this.list.map(Number);

Comment: in the option instead of value if you use ngValue, it should solve the issue. 
 <select type="number" [(ngModel)]="levelNum">
    <option *ngFor="#level of levels" [ngValue]="level.num">{{level.name}}</option>
</select>

Answer (score 0):

I think easiest solution would be to cast it to a number when you need to use it... Simple `+this.levelNum` will do. http://plnkr.co/edit/SxQfNlUB4RNdo2OndM9o