# angular2 select value object

Tags: typescript, angular, plunker

It is getting really annoying! I have an array of objects i found this solution: [How to use select/option/NgFor on an array of objects in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33181936/how-to-use-select-option-ngfor-on-an-array-of-objects-in-angular2)

but after all I am doing the same as this but if i log my $event it is undefined.. probably because it is stringified but after that not parsed back.

Here is an example of my code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row" *ngFor="#condition of conditions;#conditionindex = index">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <select class="form-control" [ngModel]="stringify(condition)" (ngModelChange)="onChange(conditionindex, $event)">
            <option *ngFor="#c of catalog;#catalogindex = index" [value]="stringify(c)">
                {{c.name}}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <condition-detail [condition]="condition"></condition-detail>
</div>

<a class="btn btn-primary" (click)="newCondition()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></a>
```

And this is the component code:

```
export class ConditionBuilderComponent implements OnInit {
conditions: Condition[] = [];
catalog: Condition[] = [];

constructor(public _conditionService: ConditionService) { }

getConditions() {
    this._conditionService.getConditions().then(conditions => this.catalog = conditions);
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.getConditions();
}

stringify(o:any): string {
    return JSON.stringify(o);
}

onChange(conditionsIndex, selectedCondition:string): void {
    console.log(typeof selectedCondition);
    //JSON.parse(selectedCondition);
    console.log(selectedCondition);
    //this.conditions[conditionsIndex] = this.catalog[condition];
    console.log(typeof selectedCondition);
}
```

Please help me out. The console log of selectedCondition is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it allready:)

Here the solution:

```
<select class="form-control" [ngModel]="condition.name" (ngModelChange)="onChange(conditionindex, $event)">
   <option *ngFor="#c of catalog;#catalogindex = index" [value]="c.name">
                {{c.name}}
   </option>
</select>
```

And the component file:

```
  onChange(conditionsIndex, selectedCondition:string): void {
    this.conditions[conditionsIndex] = this.catalog.find(condition => condition.name == selectedCondition);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With the latest Angular2 version (beta 14), support for choose as object has been added.