# Typescript: How to update select when object has changed

Tags: angular, html, typescript, ngfor

I have this html code:

```
<tr>
    <td><label>G Level 3</label></td>
    <td><select [ngModel]="selectedG3" (ngModelChange)="selectG3Changed($event)">
          <option></option>
          <option *ngFor="let g3 of gLevels3" [ngValue]="g3">{{g3.name}}</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This is my ts-code:

```
gLevels3: GLevel[];
getGLevels3(): void {
   this.httpServerService.getGLevels(3).subscribe(glevel3 => this.gLevels3 = glevel3);
}
```

*gLevels3* is an **Array** with **Objects**. I want to update the *options* of *select* every time I call the function *getGLevels3()*.

Currently it is not working. After calling the function there are still the same *options* inside the *select*.

How can I trigger the update?

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33181936/how-to-use-select-option-ngfor-on-an-array-of-objects-in-angular2?

Comment: @GetFuzzy no, but thanks. I wanted to make it easier for you to understand. actually it is working for select as I just got to know but not for a table with dynamic tablerows

Comment: Dynamic table rows sounds like you probably have a different binding problem. Might be worth a new question.

Comment: @GetFuzzy I see. Thank you anyways!

Comment: @GetFuzzy my problem is like this here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15511 but not that I get an error. It is just not updating the table.

Comment: @GetFuzzy Actually I am getting closer. It is also not possible for select's. I send an object to another components function where I push the new object into the object-array. So far so good, it works. But there won't happen anything to neither the select nor the table.

Comment: I have started a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51710175/typescript-how-to-update-table-with-dynamic-tablerows-when-object-has-changed

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have eliminated all other possibilities... Offhand your code looks correct. We have the same type of situation in a code base I work on. We have a filtering select options situation, and it is updating just fine.

```
        <select class="tool-controls__select" style="margin-right: 4px;" *ngIf="selectFilterOptions.length > 0 && chartIdsDefined" [(ngModel)]="selectedFilterOption" (change)="selectFilterOptionOnChange()">
            <option [ngValue]="filterItem" *ngFor="let filterItem of selectFilterOptions">{{filterItem}}</option>
        </select>
        <select class="tool-controls__select" [(ngModel)]="selectedOption" (change)="selectOnChange()">
            <option [ngValue]="item" *ngFor="let item of selectOptions">{{item.name}}</option>
        </select>
```