# Typescript: How to update table with dynamic tablerows when object has changed

Tags: html, angular, typescript, data-binding, ngfor

this is my html code:

```
</table>
  <tr *ngFor="let task of taskArray">
    <td>{{task.startTime}}</td>
    <td>{{task.endTime}}</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>{{task.action}}</td>
    <td>{{task.glevel1}}</td>
    <td>{{task.glevel2}}</td>
    <td>{{task.glevel3}}</td>
    <td>{{task.glevel4}}</td>
    <td>{{task.glevel5}}</td>
    <td>{{task.train}}</td>
    <td>{{task.trainType}}</td>
    <td>{{task.wagon}}</td>
    <td>{{task.repeaterWagon}}</td>
    <td>{{task.remark}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

this is my ts-code (I send an object to another component where I push the object into an object-array):

```
taskArray: Task[] = [];

fillTable(task){
  this.taskArray.push(task);
}
```

After I fired the function *fillTable(task)* it won't update the table respective won't add tablerows to the table. It seems like, my table is not updating after changing the object. Maybe it has something to do with that I send the object to another component. Because it neither work for my table nor for a select or another html-object.

I want to be able to change the object and furthermore update or alter the table.

How can I trigger the update on the table?

[UPDATE]

I should have mentioned that I included this component where the table lies like this in my "parent html":

```
<div id="taskTableDiv" style="width: 98%">
    <app-task-table></app-task-table>
</div>
```

Comment: Would it be possible with a service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to answer my question since I got to a solution:

I now use a **service** called *task-service*:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Task } from './task';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TaskService {
  taskArray: Task[] = [];

  fillTable(task: Task){
    this.taskArray.push(task);

    console.log(this.taskArray)
  }
}
```

I initiate the *task-service* like this in my ts of my table-component:

```
constructor(public taskService: TaskService) { }
```

I do the *ngFor-loop in this same component html like this in my *table-body*:

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let task of taskService.taskArray">
.
.
.
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

And like this it updates the table because the service holds the variable and keeps it up to date.

You can find a tutorial for this here: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

Answer (score 2):

Try assigning the array after you push a task. Change detection for binding isn't going to take place if you just add an item to an array that is already bound.

```
 this.taskArray = [new Task()];
```

Comment: I agree but would reassign like this: `this.taskArray = [...this.taskArray];`

Answer (score 0):

```
fillTable(task){
  this.taskArray.push(task);
  location.reload();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But it is not working for me. This reloads the whole page and I just want the table to be updated. If I reload the page it would reset everything on the page. I updated my question.

Comment: fillTable(task) will be executed onClick button or when?

Comment: Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many SO posters are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted.

Comment: it also might not solve this kind of problem, because it is like a "typically" informatics answer --> Restart your PC and look if that works.