# How to make angular select to select a selected value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options

I have selected value coming from back end in JSON and i have select element content coming from back end in the same JSON also.

Problem is that selected value is not selected in the select element, but binding works fine when i select new element.

I tried several approaches (option element ng-repeat, ng-option) all with same result. Selected value which is in data.cruiseCategoryId was not selected in select element.

My app.js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.data = {
    cruiseCategoryDropdownOptions: [{
      disabled: false,
      group: null,
      selected: false,
      text: "Interior Cabin Bella",
      value: "6"
    }, {
      disabled: false,
      group: null,
      selected: false,
      text: "Interior Cabin Fantastica",
      value: "7"
    }, {
      disabled: false,
      group: null,
      selected: false,
      text: "Oceanview Cabin Fantastica",
      value: "8"
    }, {
      disabled: false,
      group: null,
      selected: false,
      text: "Balcony Bella",
      value: "9"
    }, {
      disabled: false,
      group: null,
      selected: false,
      text: "Balcony Fantastica",
      value: "10"
    }, {
      disabled: false,
      group: null,
      selected: false,
      text: "Balcony Aurea",
      value: "11"
    }, {
      disabled: false,
      group: null,
      selected: false,
      text: "Balcony Wellness",
      value: "12"
    }, {
      disabled: false,
      group: null,
      selected: false,
      text: "Suite Fantastica",
      value: "13"
    }, {
      disabled: false,
      group: null,
      selected: false,
      text: "Suite Aurea",
      value: "14"
    }, {
      disabled: false,
      group: null,
      selected: false,
      text: "Suite Yacht Club Deluxe",
      value: "15"
    }],
    cruiseCategoryId: 10
  }
});
```

My html

```
selected value: {{data.cruiseCategoryId}}
<select class="form-control"
    name="cruiseCategoryId"
    id="cruiseCategoryId"
    ng-options="i.value as i.text for i in data.cruiseCategoryDropdownOptions track by i.value"
    ng-model="data.cruiseCategoryId">
</select>
```

Problem plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/vQxdDA

Comment: after you get back the data do a $scope.$apply() which will trigger a digest function to update the models

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated Plunker - https://plnkr.co/edit/0XApRsOwDq9uSt4u50Xx?p=preview

1. Your JSON has attribute "value" which is assigned string value Ex:`value: "10"` whereas `cruiseCategoryId` is assigned as `cruiseCategoryId: 10` change it to `cruiseCategoryId: "10"`
2. Angular Doc mentions following - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

   `Be careful when using select as and track by in the same expression.` under title `select as and track by`, so remove that

HTML :

```
<select class="form-control" name="cruiseCategoryId" id="cruiseCategoryId"
    ng-options="i.value as i.text for i in data.cruiseCategoryDropdownOptions"
    ng-model="data.cruiseCategoryId">
</select>
```

JSON : only change below

```
cruiseCategoryId: "10"
```

OPTION 2 :

HTML :

```
<select class="form-control" name="cruiseCategoryId" id="cruiseCategoryId"
    ng-options="i.value as i.text for i in data.cruiseCategoryDropdownOptions"
    ng-model="data.cruiseCategoryId.toString()">
</select>
```

JSON : no change

```
cruiseCategoryId: 10
```

Comment: I really want to use numeric type in data.cruiseCategoryId. Maybe you have any suggestions on achieving this?

Comment: @Mindaugas - keeping data types same is the best option, otherwise there are workarounds; like before binding `ng-options` change data type of value to be int `parseInt(value)` or data.cruiseCategoryId to be string data type

Comment: @Mindaugas - please check option 2, hope that resolves the issue

Comment: looks like option 2 is breaking model binding.

Answer (score 1):

Problem: We have data in a particular format and we need to send it to `ng-model` in a different format, we can use `$formatters` and/or `$parsers`, these are properties on `ngModelController`.

> Parsers

Parsers change how view values will be saved to the model.

```
ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value){
    value.toUpperCase();
    return value;
});
```

> Formatters

Formatters work in the opposite way that Parsers do. Formatters deal with data coming up from the model into the view. They will get called whenever the model changes and has to be rendered. They will also be called on the initial load of the page.

```
ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value){
    value.toUpperCase();
    return value;
});
```

And now, here are the changes we need to make to fix the problem mentioned in the question:

1.Remove `track by i.value`from ng-options.

2.Add a directive to parse and change `data.cruiseCategoryId` before sending it to `ng-model`.

Here is plunker

https://plnkr.co/edit/oGzw7pUyRAmybWXNvjCA?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

`ng-init` could be a solution on your select.

[ng-init doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)

### Edit

I advice you to isolate your model and give it a default value with your data from your JSON.
See your plunker updated :

https://plnkr.co/edit/a76v11FDlUii2YI9ccvl?p=preview

### Update

Few solutions already exists here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31643062/5566936

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your track by statement breaks it. Use `track by $index`.

Answer (score 0):

I made following two changes and it worked:

1.Changed the value of `cruiseCategoryId`in `$scope.data`from number 10 to string '10'.

2.Removed `track by i.value`from ng-options.

Here is plunker

https://plnkr.co/edit/oGzw7pUyRAmybWXNvjCA?p=preview

Comment: That id in number on purpose. We store integer in the db. I would prefer to keep it as it is and solve the issue.